# Scraper clicking on the next page button but fetches nothing

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in vba in combination with selenium to parse data from different tables spreading across multiple pages. When I run my script I can see that it parses data from the first page and then keep clicking on next page button until there is no more button is available. However, I'm getting the data from first page and seeing the browser clicking on the next page button for nothing cause it doesn't fetch any data from other pages. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Perhaps, the loop I have created has got something to do with it or I don't know. Thanks for taking a look into it. Here is the full code:

```
Sub Table_data()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    Dim tabl As Object, rdata As Object, cdata As Object

    driver.Get "https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam"
    driver.Wait 1000

    For Each tabl In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//table[@class='fe-datatable']")
        For Each rdata In tabl.FindElementsByXPath(".//tr")
            For Each cdata In rdata.FindElementsByXPath(".//td")
                y = y + 1
                Cells(x + 1, y) = cdata.Text
            Next cdata
            x = x + 1
            y = 0
        Next rdata
        driver.FindElementByLinkText("Next").Click
        driver.Wait 1000
    Next tabl
End Sub
```

Comment: It returns nothing for the latter pages because you click the next button inside your loop. You should take `driver.FindElementByLinkText("Next").Click` outside of your loops so that it recognizes the table for the next page. Consider using another loop to press Next button.Also you are parsing the wrong table, you should be parsing `class="fe-fund-tableBody"`. This way you get rid of page numbers. If I were you I would have done it completely in a different way.

Comment: Finally found you, Tehscript. When I see you in any of my thread it seems that I was suffering from a diseases and come across a physician. Get back to you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider pressing the Next button outside of your loops. You should use it within another loop, and the loop should terminate when there is no more Next button to press (Run-time Error 7: NoSuchElementError)

Xpath `//table[@class='fe-datatable']` returns Page numbers as well. You should be using the inner table which is `//table[@class='fe-fund-tableBody']` by class name or if you seek by id `//*[@id='docRows']`. They will point to the same element.

You might have noticed there are 7 occurrences of the above mentioned element. Your code loops through the empty ones for each page. You can avoid this by looping through the first occurence only, like this:  `(//table[@class='fe-fund-tableBody'])[1]` or `(//*[@id='docRows'])[1]`.

I also would recommend to find a way to `implicit/explicit wait` instead of `wait`. If we don't go further to improve anything else, in the end your code should look something like this:

```
Sub Table_data()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    Dim tabl As Object, rdata As Object, cdata As Object

    driver.Get "https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam"
    driver.Wait 1000
    Do
        For Each tabl In driver.FindElementsByXPath("(//*[@id='docRows'])[1]") 'or "(//table[@class='fe-fund-tableBody'])[1]"
            For Each rdata In tabl.FindElementsByXPath(".//tr")
                For Each cdata In rdata.FindElementsByXPath(".//td")
                    y = y + 1
                    Cells(x + 1, y) = cdata.Text
                Next cdata
                x = x + 1
                y = 0
            Next rdata
        Next tabl

        On Error Resume Next
        driver.FindElementByLinkText("Next").Click
        driver.Wait 1000
    Loop Until Err.Number = 7
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the scraper needs a little more twitch. It does loops successfully but it keeps a long gap in the spreadsheet between each table.

Comment: @SMth80 Have you included the `(xpath)[1]` that I mentioned above?

Comment: Feel like irritating you a bit, Tehscript. Here is a link to a new thread I've just created. If you have time you can go it through. Thanks.  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416258/post-request-created-in-vba-brings-back-nothing-as-result"

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would change the way you are iterating the pages. It should be like this in **pseudo code**:

```
function element getNextButton(){
    all_buttons = driver.findElementsByXpath("""//*[@id="Price_1_1"]/tfoot/tr/td/div/div/a""");
    next_button = all_buttons[all_buttons.Size()-1];
    return next_button;
}

main(){
    next_button = getNextButton();
    while true{
        do something with your current table;
        next_button.click();
        wait(2); // wait some time till the page loads
        next_button = getNextButton();
        if next_button.text does not contains 'Next'{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have just tested it on Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def get_next_button():
    buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="Price_1_1"]/tfoot/tr/td/div/div/a""")
    next_element_button = buttons[len(buttons)-1]
    return next_element_button

chrome_path = r"chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam")
time.sleep(5)

next_button =get_next_button()

while(True):
    # Do something with the table
    next_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    next_button = get_next_button()
    if 'Next' not in next_button.text:
        break

print 'End'
```

I am not familiar with vba, but if you do not understand Python I can try to translate it to vba.

**EDIT**

An "approximation" to VBA solution should be this (please check syntax errors, I have never used VBA):

```
Function GetNextElement() as Object
    Dim all_buttons As Object
    Dim next_button As Object
    all_buttons= driver.FindElementsByXpath("""//*[@id="Price_1_1"]/tfoot/tr/td/div/div/a""")
    next_button = all_buttons[all_buttons.Length-1]
    Return next_button 
End Function

Sub Table_data()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    Dim position as Integer
    Dim next_button As Object
    driver.Get "https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam"
    driver.Wait 1000
    next_button = GetNextElement()

    Do While True
        // Do something with the table
        next_button.Click
        driver.Wait 2000
        next_button = GetNextElement()
        position = InStr(next_button.Text,"Next")
        If position = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If      
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar Martinez, for your answer. I've already got it working using python. However, I would like to do it with vba as well.

Comment: @SMth80 see the last edit. I have tried to approximate my Python code to VBA. I have never programmed with VBA so please check it and correct the code, sorry. Perhaps you should define `driver` as global variable (or just send it as parameter to the function `GetNextElement(driver As Object)`)

Comment: Sorry  Oscar Martinez for the delayed response. I didn't notice and test your edited code but it looks nice. Will give it a try real soon. Thanks.