# POST request created in vba brings back nothing as result

Tags: vba, post, web-scraping

I've written a very tiny script in vba using POST request. However, when I run it, I get nothing as result except for a blank message. I've tried to fill in the request parameter accordingly. Perhaps, I can't notice which should be included in the parameter. The page I'm dealing with contains several images in it's right panel. When an image is clicked the request about which i'm talking here is sent to the server and brings back the result and displays new information concerning its' flavor under it. My goal is to parse all the flavors connected to each images. Anyways, I'm trying to attach all the things necessary to find out what i'm missing. Thanks in advance.

This is what I got from chrome developer tools to prepare the POST request:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjn0ahixhu58miq/RequestStatus.txt?dl=0"

Here is what I'm trying with:

```
Sub PostReq()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim ArgumentStr As String

    ArgumentStr = "opt=flavor&opt1=207&opt2=47&ip=105"
    With http
        .Open "POST", "https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
        .send ArgumentStr
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    MsgBox http.responseText

End Sub
```

This is the original link to the webpage:

"https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/"

Comment: your request header says `urlencoded` but your argument string isn't encoded. Have you tried that? Or pass as a GET request instead

Comment: Thanks Macro Man , for your suggestion. I think I'm getting there. Please include it as an answer and a little description why should it be encoded so that other's with the same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've made it. To receive the required response it is necessary to send a GET request first then again send a POST request using the response from that get request. Here is the working one:

```
Sub httpPost()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim ArgumentStr As String

    ArgumentStr = "opt=flavor&opt1=207&opt2=47&ip=105"

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/", False
        .send
    End With

    With http
        .Open "POST", "https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php", False
        .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
        .send ArgumentStr
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    MsgBox http.responseText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets a request header like so:

```
.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

so the script is going to expect the argument string to be URL encoded (which it isn't).

Try either encoding the string, or send the request using "`GET`" instead.

Comment: Just get back to you Macro Man. It does give response but no data is there. Here is the link what my script is sending request to: "https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php&opt=flavor&opt1=207&opt2=47&ip=105"

Comment: Yes, your link is sending the data via a GET request, not a POST request so you need to do the same in your code

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't get to the target page whether I make it using "GET" request or "POST". However, if i try to follow chrome developer tool then "POST" request is clearly mentioned there.

Comment: Your browser may be sending a POST request because of another script form that site. There could also be other things at play such as `$_SESSION` variables that you can't see which contribute to that script. Without knowing what the script is expecting it's impossible to know why you aren't getting a result.